# How do I properly test an API Controller that returns json for a non null response?

Tags: c#, json, moq, asp.net-web-api2, mstest

I have this test method for testing an API controller, that returns a JSON string, for a non null response.

```
[TestClass]
public class TransactionsTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void ColorPerformance_GetChartData_NotNullResponse_Test()
    {
        // Arrange
        string quality = null, cars = null, year = "2015";

        var listColorPerformanceChartData = new List<ColorPerformanceChartData>();
        var mockRepository = new Mock<IColorPerformanceRepository>();
        mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetChartData(quality, cars, year))
            .Returns(listColorPerformanceChartData);

        var controller = new ColorPerformanceController(mockRepository.Object);

        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.GetChartData(quality, cars, year);
        var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<object>;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);
    }
}
```

This test is passing in that `contentResult` is not null. However, I am not feeling sure that the test is written properly for the following reasons:

1. `contentResult.Content` has empty data, in that there is no data being returned from `_repository.GetChartData()` method, but is not empty because still the json constructed is as follows:

`{ categories = {int[0]}, series = { name = "Number of colors", data = {double[0]} } }`

2. `contentResult.ContentNegotiator`, `contentResult.Formatter` and `contentResult.Request` all are throwing an exception of `InvalidOperationException` with the message `HttpControllerContext.Configuration must not be null.` I don't know why this is happening.

The API Controller:

```
public class ColorPerformanceController : ApiController
{
    private IColorPerformanceRepository _repository;
    public ColorPerformanceController(IColorPerformanceRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
    public IHttpActionResult GetChartData(string quality, string cars, string year)
    {
        try 
        {
            var data = ProcessData(quality, cars, year);
            return Ok(data);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
    private object ProcessData(string quality, string cars, string year)
    {
        var data = _repository.GetChartData(quality, cars, year);
        return new {
            categories = data.Select(d => d.Id).ToArray(),
            series = new[] { new { name = "Number of colors", data = data.Select(d => d.CumulativePercentage).ToArray() }}
        };
    }
}
```

IColorPerformanceRepository:

```
public interface IColorPerformanceRepository
{
    IEnumerable<ColorPerformanceChartData> GetChartData(string quality, string cars, string year);
}
```

The object returned from the repository implementation:

```
public class ColorPerformanceChartData
{
    private double _cumulativePercentage;
    public double CumulativePercentage {
        get { return Math.Round(_cumulativePercentage, 2); }
        set { _cumulativePercentage = value; }
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: did you try debugging the test to see where it's throwing the error?

Comment: Yes, I did debug the test and its not really failing anywhere. As mentioned, the test is passing. It's just that I don't see any data come through from the `_repository.GetChartData()` call. Is this because I am just mocking the behaviour or am I supposed to get data?

Comment: okay, it's a bit unclear what you're asking then because you mention that `...and contentResult.Request all are throwing an exception of InvalidOperationException...`

Comment: I was really not sure whether what I have is a sufficient test due to the two reasons I mentioned. I was expecting some data from the `_repository.GetChartData()` method, but then realized that the MockRepository doesn't really call the actual repository method.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Best practice is you should avoid using anonymous type in this case:

```
private object ProcessData(string quality, string cars, string year)
    {
        var data = _repository.GetChartData(quality, cars, year);
        return new {
            categories = data.Select(d => d.Id).ToArray(),
            series = new[] { new { name = "Number of colors", data = data.Select(d => d.CumulativePercentage).ToArray() }}
        };
    }
```

Try defining a class for it so that you can de-serialize the string and check each property:

```
        // Act
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = controller.GetChartData(quality, cars, year);
        //Notice I use YourClass instead of object here.
        var contentResult = actionResult as OkNegotiatedContentResult<YourClass>;

        // Assert
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult);   
        Assert.IsNotNull(contentResult.Content);   
        //Assert all properties of contentResult.Content like categories, series,..
```

Regarding the exception, try:

```
var controller = new ColorPerformanceController(mockRepository.Object);
//Add these 2 lines
 controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
 controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
```

From http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-controllers-in-web-api

Comment: I understand it is better to avoid anonymous types, but the reason to go for anonymous object was to create a JSON string in a specific format that the frontend charts library accepts.

Comment: @Animesh: I don't understand why that reason limits you to using anonymous types.

Comment: There is no absolute reason, it was something created quick and dirty based on the changing requirements. But apart from huge improvements in readability and maintainabilty by returning a strongly typed class, I am curious to know if there are any other advantages. I would add that I might bite the bullet sooner or later and create strongly typed classes.

Comment: @Animesh: I think they're the main advantages. I think another advantage is in this case, you can access its properties at compilation time